# css animation during heavy js computations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a method in javascript program that sometimes makes heavy computations (I can not even assume when), I wanted to notify the user that something is going on in the background and he cannot access data for now as it is processing, did it with an animation in css, but when that heavy computation occurs browser doesn't even fires the animation, but freezes instead. Tried some hacks with setInterval and setTimeout, but they doesn't work as expected. The only reasonable solution I just found was using a webWorkers which in my situation would expect a lot of refactor to work. Is there any other trick that comes to your mind to let javascript do its job and in the same time show the user that the processing is happening?

Thank you

Comment: No, javascript runs on the ui thread, which means ui updates and code execution can never happen at the same time. Web workers are designed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try displaying an animated gif (think the YouTube loading circle) just before making your computations and hiding it with the `display: none` CSS property when the computations are finished.